# Omit wrapper tags in JAXB when the collection is empty

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

In JAXB, you can use the @XmlElementWrapper attribute to specify tags to wrap a collection of elements.  However, these wrapper tags appear even if the collection is empty (they don't appear if the collection is `null`).  Is there any way to have JAXB omit the wrapper tags if the collection is empty?  Using adapters on the collection doesn't seem to work, since JAXB interprets this to mean it should apply the adapter to each element in the collection.

Answer (score 5):

You can enforce your desired behavior in a somewhat hackish way by using
[Marshal Event Callbacks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback).

```
@XmlRootElement(name="example")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Example {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="wrapper")
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private List<Item> items;

    // invoked by Marshaller before marshalling
    private void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) {
         if (items != null && items.isEmpty())
            items = null;
    }

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

As described in [Marshal Event Callbacks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback)
there are actually 2 alternative ways how to use marshal callbacks:

1. Put the `beforeMarshal` and/or `afterMarshal` method directly into your class, and that's it. (This is the simpler way, and that's why I used this in my answer).
2. Create a [Marshaller.Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.Listener.html) and write the `beforeMarshal` and `afterMarshal` methods there. You would then need to register this listener in your `Marshaller`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use listener mechanism of `Marshaller`

You can add/set a listener like below :

```
jaxbMarshaller.setListener( new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeMarshal(Object source) 
    {
        if ( source instanceof MyCollectionWrapper )
        {
            MyCollectionWrapper wrapper = (MyCollectionWrapper)source;
            if ( wrapper.getCollection() != null && wrapper.getCollection().isEmpty() )
            {
                wrapper.setCollection( null );
            }
        }

    }
});
```

where `MyCollectionWrapper` is the class representing your wrapper class.

This should remove the wrapper tag when the collection is empty.